# Explain Inherited Roles

Tags: liferay, roles, administration, inherited

The inherited roles are the roles which appear as shown in the image:

[image: inherited roles image]

So my questions are:

1. What are inherited roles? Please explain.
2. What are the use-cases in which roles would appear in this section for a User?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (for example) be member of a UserGroup which is assigned a role. This would not be editable on the user profile, but an effective role that is good to see if it's there. The other "independent" roles (e.g. through an organization) should also appear there.

Comment: **1)** So you are saying that, only if roles are given to UserGroups and Organization it will appear in the inherited roles section. **2)** If I make the UserGroup a member of a Site and give Site roles like Site-Admin or Site-Owner to that UserGroup then would I be able to see those roles in the inherited Roles section if I am a member of this UserGroup?

Comment: 1) If you don't insist on the *only*: Yes (might be only, but I wouldn't want to go that far. 2) These indirect assignments are a beast when talking about them in just plain text - easiest if you try it out yourself. I have the feeling that there's a possibility for misunderstanding in that scenario, so this will give you the definitive answer. In short: If a user gets some permission on any way other than a directly assigned role, that information should be visible in the "inherited roles"

Comment: Ok Thanks. The reason I cited that particular case in point-2 is that the Site-owner or other site-roles are not appearing in the inherited roles section though the user is able to perform all the actions. For Organizations I can see the roles and custom role assigned to UserGroup it is being displayed but not that particular case of a Site role assigned to a UserGroup. Can it be a bug? :-)

Comment: I currently don't have time to try to reproduce, but if I understand you correctly: yes, could be. In this case, please file at https://issues.liferay.com

Comment: Thanks Olaf Kock for all the help and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Inherited roles can be configured in:
Control Panel > Roles > Select a particular role > Assign Members > Select the Sites tab

Inherited Roles

Inherited roles really not existed in the liferay but we can see these roles in the user my account page roles section .these roles specially appear when the user can be member of user group which is assigned a role.

We can say if any roles which associates with User Group and the user is member of respective user group then role can be visible as part of inherited roles section.

Simply we can say that user directly not associated with role instead of that User Group will be associated with role and the user will be member of User Group then the roles are become as inherited role to users who are belong to User Group.